# counting the number of non-negative integer pairs of $a+2b+3c+4d=100$

Tags: combinatorics

I thought partition number $P(n,4)$ is equal with 
the number of non-negative integer pairs $a+2b+3c+4d=n-4$

so....

how do I count the number of integer pairs satisfying $a+2b+3c+4d=100$ over $a,b,c,d \geq 0$ ??

I really wonder this problem!

thank you for sharing your knowledge.

please don't use a computer

Comment: I won't call $(a,b,c,d)$ a *pair*, anyway you just need a coefficient in the Maclaurin series of $$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)}=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n,$$ and due to the pole of order $4$ at $x=1$,  $$a_n\approx \frac{1}{24}\binom{n+3}{3}.$$

Comment: Since $x=-1$ is a double pole, there is a significative (linear) perturbation due to the parity of $n$. The other poles contribute with a bounded arithmetic perturbation.

Comment: The estimate by @JackD'Aurizio comes out to $\approx7369$ for $n=100.$  Counting with a python script  gives $8037.$  So, about a $10\%$ error.

Comment: If you expand Jack D'Aurizio's generating function by partial fractions you could get an expression something like $a_n = c_1 + c_2 n + c_3 n^2 + c_4 n^3 + c_5 (-1)^n + c_6 n (-1)^n + c_7 \cos(2 \pi n/3) + c_8 \sin(2 \pi n/3) + c_9 \cos(\pi n/2) + c_{10} \sin(\pi n/2)$.  Quite a bit of work to do by hand, though.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: not so much, just done.

Comment: It is interesting to point out that an initial approximation with a bounded *relative* error can be turned into an approximation with a bounded *absolute* error. This happens in the Ramanujan-Rademacher approximation of $p(n)$, too, not by chance.

Comment: wow...even though i am in the department of engineering, i comprehend what you say. all thing you say is helpful for me but  i  also want a basic approch because i simply solve  the number of tuples of a+2b+3c=100 over a,b,c>=0  in method that a+2b+3c=100<->2b+3c<=100->2b<=100,2b<=97,2b<=94.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding my comment: if we consider the partial fraction decomposition of $f(z)=\frac{1}{(1-z)(1-z^2)(1-z^3)(1-z^4)}=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n z^n$ we have that the pole at $z=1$ contributes with

$$ \frac{1}{24(1-z)^4}+\frac{1}{8(1-z)^3}+\frac{59}{288(1-z)^2}+\frac{17}{72(1-z)} $$
to $f(z)$, hence it contributes with
$$ \frac{2n^3+30n^2+135n+175}{288}$$
to $a_n$. The pole at $z=-1$ contributes with
$$ (-1)^n \frac{n+5}{32} $$
and the other poles provide bounded contributions, since they are simple. It follows that for even values of $n$
$$ a_n \approx \frac{(n+5)(n^2+10n+22)}{144} $$
and for $n=100$ the ceiling of the RHS is exactly $a_{100}$, i.e. $8037$. The error of this approximation is bounded by twice the sum of the absolute values of the real parts of the residues at the simple poles, i.e. $\frac{2}{9}<\frac{1}{2}$. In particular

> If $n$ is even $a_n=[x^n]\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)}$ **is** the closest integer to $\frac{(n+5)(n^2+10n+22)}{144}.$
>   If $n$ is odd $a_n=[x^n]\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)}$ **is** the closest integer to $\frac{(n+5)(n^2+10n+13)}{144}.$

Answer (score 3):

I claim that the number of such tuples is equal to the number of partitions of 100 into 4 nonnegative integers.

Indeed, let $S=\{(a,b,c,d): a+2b+3c+4d=100\}$, and let $S'=\{(A,B,C,D): A+B+C+D=100, A\ge B\ge C\ge D\}$.

I claim that $S$ and $S'$ are in bijection. To see this, we will define two inverse maps between the two sets.

Given $(a,b,c,d)\in S$, we obtain $(A,B,C,D)\in S'$ by taking
 $A=a+b+c+d$,$B=b+c+d$, $C=c+d$ and $D=d$. Conversely, given $(A,B,C,D)\in S'$, we have $(a,b,c,d)\in S$ where $d=D, c=D-C, b=B-C, a=A-B$, and it is readily verified that these are inverse assignments.

In particular, the number of tuples you wish to count is equal to the cardinatlity of $S'$.

Note that $S'$ is in bijection with the set of partitions of $100$ into 4 nonnegative integers. The cardinality can be expressed in terms of the partition function $p(n,k)=$ number of partitions of n into k *positive* integers. Indeed, the tuple (A,B,C,D) may have 0,1,2, or 3 terms equal to 0, so we have $|S'|=p(100,4)+p(100,3)+p(100,2)+p(100,1)$. The function $p(n,k)$ satisfies various recurrence relations that can be found on this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory).